I tried nomal map of tshirt. But Buffering stops at 1% continuously
I tried using a Normal Map, but I failed. It stopped at 1% buffering and then finished. I think the normal map is not working properly. The Image Texture below is just blue and doesn't show the texture I want. How can I solve this problem?



2 m extrusion seems enormous, have you tried a lower value ?

Yes, I tried various value 0.01~10 m. But the result is same. It stops at 1% buffering and finished continuously.

Could you show the modifier and their settings on these objects ?

I think you have to change your Image Texture node's Color Space from sRGB to Non Color.

I tried that Image Texture node's Color Space from sRGB to Non Color.  But the result is same. It stops at 1% buffering and finished continuously.

The Material in which there's the texture node you want to bake on is not assigned to the faces of the shirt model, so it's like it wasn't there.
As lights aren't involved in baking, use low number of samples (4, 2 or even 1 only) to speed up the process.


Thank you. I solved problem from your answer!
